# How to print dynamic generated values of form field in selenium using Eclipes.

Tags: eclipse, forms, selenium, printing

Here I want to print dynamic generated "Shipping rate" of some products in the Cart. 
For ex,  After adding product to cart, on the checkout process after entering shipping address by user, SHIPPING RATE are dynamic generated  by the store. Now i want print that shipping Rate. 
Id= "data-checkout-total-shipping-target"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Surya's answer is correct. Alongwith that, you can also try the below code for the result:

```
String price = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='total-line__name' and contains(text(),'Shipping')]/following-sibling::strong")).getText();
```

**Note:-** In the above code, you can replace the text **'Shipping'** with **'Subtotal'** or **'Taxes'** or **'Total'** too, to retrieve their respective texts.

---

Here, is the updated code as you asked for:-

```
public class Testing
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException{

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); //Opening firefox instance

        driver.manage().window().maximize(); //maximizing window

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //Giving implicit timeout of 20 seconds

        driver.get("http://testing-671.myshopify.com/"); //Navigating to url

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@alt='testing']")).click(); //Clicking on Testing product

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='add-to-cart']")).click(); //Clicking on Add to cart button

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='checkout']")).click(); //Clicking on Checkout button

        //Clearing and sending value in email
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='checkout_email']")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='checkout_email']")).sendKeys("test@gmail.com");

        //Clearing and sending value in first name
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='checkout_shipping_address_first_name']")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='checkout_shipping_address_first_name']")).sendKeys("Test");

        //Clearing and sending value in last name
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='checkout_shipping_address_last_name']")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='checkout_shipping_address_last_name']")).sendKeys("Test");

        //Clearing and sending value in address
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='checkout_shipping_address_address1']")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='checkout_shipping_address_address1']")).sendKeys("Test Address");

        //Clearing and sending value in city
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='checkout_shipping_address_city']")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='checkout_shipping_address_city']")).sendKeys("Test City");

        //Selecting India as Country
        Select sel = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='checkout_shipping_address_country']")));
        sel.selectByVisibleText("India");

        //Selecting Goa as Province
        sel = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='checkout_shipping_address_province']")));
        sel.selectByVisibleText("Goa");

        //Clearing and sending value in Zip
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='checkout_shipping_address_zip']")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='checkout_shipping_address_zip']")).sendKeys("789088");

        //Clicking on Continue button
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Continue']")).click();

        //Waiting till the text changes from "—" to some price value.
        new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementWithText(By.xpath("//span[@class='total-line__name' and contains(text(),'Shipping')]/following-sibling::strong"), "—"));     

        //Getting the price of Shipping
        String price = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='total-line__name' and contains(text(),'Shipping')]/following-sibling::strong")).getText();

        //Printing price of shipping
        System.out.println("The price of Shipping is: "+price);
}
```

Comment: Hey subh, i tried your code but get the same "java.lang.NullPointerException" error. 
Can yo give me the test case that you run

Comment: @user3159596 : I have added the code above. Please check.

Comment: Hey Subh, thanks for this Help of code. But i cannot able to understand this code. 
So i posted a new question with the full code those i get from selenium IDE, Here is the link. Please help me on this question, given format. Please edit on the same code so i run them and get the desire result.(Able to print shipping Rate i.e Rs 8)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27124598/

Comment: Actually, I am using Selenium-2, i.e., Selenium WebDriver for coding. The link you've shared is by using Selenium RC.

Comment: Thanks for understanding and Help.

Comment: Hey, please explain why you use "for loop"

Comment: @user3159596: Here, it waits 60 seconds till the text "Rs." appears in the text/innerHTML of the Shipping price. You must've seen "-" appears when the page is loading and then it changes to the amount, say "Rs. 8.00". That's why I am waiting till that text appears in the innerHTML and then come out of the **For loop**, retrieve the Shipping Price and print it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
  //Get the rate - updated with currect xpath
    String rate = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//strong[@data-checkout-total-shipping-target]")).getText(); //shipping-option__price
    //Print it in Eclipse console
    System.out.println("Rate is " + rate);
```

Comment: Thanks for this Answer. But i cannot able to print the shipping rate

Comment: Can you post your html code please? or this is public website?

Comment: please check this testing website on this URL: testing-671.myshopify.com 1. Add the testing product to cart 2. Go to checkout page 3. Enter all detail 4. After entering the address, on the clicking "Continue" You redirected to the next page, on this page shipping rate appeared. Now i want to print this Shipping price.

Comment: Updated with correct xpath, please check now. The one you provide ("data-checkout-total-shipping-target") is not an element id, its one of the attribute of that element.

Comment: Thanks for this Help. But this Code i will try tomorrow.

Comment: I am trying this code, but i am getting "java.lang.NullPointerException"  error

Comment: Which line you are getting error? Can you post your updated script?

Comment: I am getting this Error on the line from where your given code start. 
Can you please give me the test-case

Comment: Surya, can you give the code you are runing on the eclipes.

Comment: I have not created entire test case, its not my job :)