# Using Selenium how I Print the shipping rate on the checkout page

Tags: eclipse, selenium, automated-tests

I want to print the Shipping rate those come on the checkout process, Shipping is calculated dynamically, on the bases of address or may be product in the Cart. I want to print the Shipping rate those come on the 2nd checkout page after calculation.

```
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class testing {
    private Selenium selenium;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://testing-671.myshopify.com/");
    selenium.start();
}

@Test
public void testtesting() throws Exception {
    selenium.open("/");
    selenium.click("link=Testing");
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    selenium.click("//a[contains(text(),'Catalog')]");
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    selenium.click("css=img[alt=\"testing\"]");
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    selenium.click("id=add-to-cart");
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    selenium.click("id=checkout");
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    selenium.type("id=checkout_email", "tester@gmail.com");
    selenium.type("id=checkout_shipping_address_first_name", "test");
    selenium.type("id=checkout_shipping_address_last_name", "test");
    selenium.type("id=checkout_shipping_address_company", "test");
    selenium.type("id=checkout_shipping_address_address1", "test");
    selenium.type("id=checkout_shipping_address_address2", "test");
    selenium.type("id=checkout_shipping_address_city", "test");
    selenium.select("id=checkout_shipping_address_country", "label=Albania");
    selenium.click("css=option[value=\"Albania\"]");
    selenium.select("id=checkout_shipping_address_country", "label=India");
    selenium.select("id=checkout_shipping_address_province", "label=Chandigarh");
    selenium.type("id=checkout_shipping_address_zip", "160062");
    selenium.click("name=commit");
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    selenium.stop();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the updated code that I've retrieved by running in Selenium IDE and exporting the testcase as program for Selenium RC and junit:

```
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Testcases {
    private Selenium selenium;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://testing-671.myshopify.com");
        selenium.start();
    }

    @Test
    public void testCases() throws Exception {
        selenium.open("/");
        selenium.click("link=Testing");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("");
        selenium.click("//a[contains(text(),'Catalog')]");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("css=img[alt=\"testing\"]");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("id=add-to-cart");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("id=checkout");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.type("id=checkout_email", "tester@gmail.com");
        selenium.type("id=checkout_shipping_address_first_name", "test");
        selenium.type("id=checkout_shipping_address_last_name", "test");
        selenium.type("id=checkout_shipping_address_company", "test");
        selenium.type("id=checkout_shipping_address_address1", "test");
        selenium.type("id=checkout_shipping_address_address2", "test");
        selenium.type("id=checkout_shipping_address_city", "test");
        selenium.select("id=checkout_shipping_address_country", "label=Albania");
        selenium.select("id=checkout_shipping_address_province", "label=Chandigarh");
        selenium.type("id=checkout_shipping_address_zip", "160062");
        selenium.click("name=commit");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        for (int second = 0;; second++) {
            if (second >= 60) fail("timeout");
            try { if (selenium.isElementPresent("//span[@class='total-line__name' and contains(text(),'Shipping')]/following-sibling::strong[contains(text(),'Rs.')]")) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }

        String Price = selenium.getText("//span[@class='total-line__name' and contains(text(),'Shipping')]/following-sibling::strong");
        System.out.println(Price);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        selenium.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad that it worked out.. :) Please mark it as an answer also. Thanks.. :)

Comment: Hey @subh
stackoverflow.com/questions/27644839/ please answer my this question

Comment: Hey @subh i have one question can you please help me to solve.
Here i want to print the class the name "total-line__name", how this i do. Using the Selenium Webdrivers